# Joomla - photo gallery with tags & drop down menu

Tags: jquery, joomla

I got a site on Joomla 3 about furniture.

and client wants to have many images on one page (like a big photo gallery).
Each picture should have several tags (e.g. kitchen, bathroom, etc), 
and there should be a search field or a drop down menu where people can select what pictures they want to see.

For example if they make a choice to see only Kitchens - then all the other pictures disappear.

Is there any Joomla extension like this?

I thought of making it all from scratch (jQuery etc), which doesn't sound too hard, but decided first to see if someone already did this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out tz_portfolio, it should do the trick, just follow the docs...

-=EDIT=-

[tz_portfolio](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/19217) @jommla extension directory

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/templaza/tz_portfolio)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: i am sorry but in my common sense he asked: `Is there any Joomla extension like this?` and i gave him the answere.... `yes there is... check it out...` and if a link is considered necessary: no problem.... is it so hard to use a search engine on a given search query?

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 3.1 [supports tags](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.1%3aHow_To_Use_Content_Tags_in_Joomla!), which are designed to work with other components than content, too. So you can either wait for a gallery to support tags, or adapt one.

Answer (score 1):

Phoca Gallery is a great, notoriously full featured gallery plugin.
I've used it before with great success on all previous versions (and 3.0).  Jan the developer does a great job staying up to date with the Joomla core changes and is on top of support also.

It takes a little getting used to how to get it to display, but there is plenty of documentation and a huge support base on his site.

Check it out.